# Finding basis for a matrix corresponding a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Suppose I was given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ that corresponds to a transformation $\alpha_A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. The basis of this $A$ corresponding to $\alpha_A$ isn't given. Now I am asked to find the matrix corresponding to $\alpha_A$ with respect to another basis, say $\{v_1,v_2\}$. How do I do this?

My solution for this is as follows:

Let $B$ be the matrix corresponding to $\alpha_A$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $A$ would then be
$$
A=S^{-1}BS
$$
such that the elements of $S$ corresponds to the basis of $A$, i.e. if $w_i$ is the basis of $A$ for $\alpha_A$, then$$
w_i=(s_{1i}, s_{2i},....s_{ni})^T
$$
From here I can get the $S$ matrix and therefore get the basis $w_i$. From these I can then get the change of basis matrix from basis $w_i$ to $v_i$, and from there the matrix of $\alpha_A$ with respect to $v_i$.

But now my problem is how do I find the matrix of $\alpha_A$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. the matrix $B$)?

Is this the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: In a particular thing, suppose I have a matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 4 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, corresponding to $\alpha_A:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $v\rightarrow Av$. How do I find the matrix of $\alpha_A$ with respect to the new basis $v_1=(4,2)^T$ and $v_1=(2,6)^T$?